# How does llvm ir handle different kind of short circuits?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, short-circuit-evaluation

For the following code in C:

```
void test(int a, int b, int c){
   if(a > 1 && (b == 2 || c == 3))
      b = a + c;
   else
      c = a + b;
   return;
}
```

The CFG is as following:

[image]

But when I change the if on line 2 to while:

```
void test(int a, int b, int c){
   while(a > 1 && (b == 2 || c == 3))
      b = a + c;
   c = a + b;
   return;
}
```

Then the CFG is changed to:

[image]

So the basic block lor.end and land.end are generated, but they are not corresponding to any statement in the program. Why does while.cond not connects to while.end directly just like entry -> if.else in the first CFG? In other words, why are lor.end and land.end generated? It seems that the way of handling short circuits in if statements are different from that in loop statements. What causes this difference?

compiling script(calng/llvm 7.0.1): clang -emit-llvm -c -g -fno-discard-value-names file_name.c

Comment: I wonder if these things would be clearer to you if you were to look at the conditions used for branching rather than the block names?

Comment: In the first program, a>1, b==2 and c==3 correspond to entry, land.lhs.true and lor.lhs.false in CFG respectivly. In the second program, a>1, b==2 and c==3 correspond to while.cond, land.rhs and lor.rhs in CFG respectivly. But there is an additional land.end, which doesn't correspond to any statement in the second program.